# React-django on cpanel - MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet

Tags: python, reactjs, django, cpanel

I am developing a React-Django application and **it runs locally**.
When I install it on a server running on cpanel, it just shows a blank page.
My provider checked it and made the following statements:

1. The python application **is installed correctly on cpanel**
2. The cause of the error **should be found on the developer side**.

I made the simplest possible application: Simpletest
**Local mode**:
"Simple Test" text appears in the title and under the react logo

[image]

**cpanel**: Python application:
the text "Simple Test" appears only in the title and sends the following error message
[image]

Does anyone have any idea where I can look for the error?

The application can be cloned from this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/jimi-lizy/Simpletest).

I would like to ask someone to try and install it on a server running cpanel. Does it have an application running?

Many thanks!